# UIColor - getRed: ... - raises exception

Tags: ios, ios4

I have the following test code:

```
CGFloat endRed, endGreen, endBlue, endAlpha;

[[UIColor greenColor] getRed:&endRed green:&endGreen blue:&endBlue alpha:&endAlpha];
```

that I call inside drawRect method for an UIView class.
This code fails with exception

```
2011-11-06 02:29:28.671 Chartous[13457:b303] -[UICachedDeviceRGBColor getRed:green:blue:alpha:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e7ea10
2011-11-06 02:29:28.673 Chartous[13457:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICachedDeviceRGBColor getRed:green:blue:alpha:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e7ea10'
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: @odyodyodys - it is far too early to nag for an accepted answer, the question is only 45 minutes old and the op hasn't even been on the site since the two current answers were posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is available in ios5 and later only. Are you running it on an earlier iOS version on the simulator or device? I assume so given the tag on your question.

Comment: yes indeed, this was the problem. I updated to iOS5 and everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 27):

Try another approach:

```
const CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
CGFloat red = components[0];
CGFloat green = components[1];
CGFloat blue = components[2];
CGFloat alpha = CGColorGetAlpha([[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
```

Comment: It should be `CGColor` instead of `cgColor` incase anyone gets instance method -'cgColor' not found and wonder why

Comment: Note, if your color comes from [UIColor whiteColor] class method, this code gives you wrong R, G, B values, it's yellow instead of white if you reassemble it back. 
I noticed, that in this case CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(cgColor) gives you 2! which is important, because you expect 4 components. 
Guess one should avoid using [UIColor whiteColor] if you need to get components later.

Comment: @krafter or could avoid using whiteColor and assemble it using components (which is bad)

Comment: @odyodyodys - assembling from components is quite OK also, I guess:

const CGFloat components[4] = {0.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0};

UIColor *whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components)] ];

Answer (score 4):

In the case of monotone colors, the number of components is 2 so you need another check unfortunately

E.g.
[UIColor whitecolor] has only 2 components for alpha and the color

```
size_t num = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(cgPrevColor);
CGFloat r,g,b;
if(num==2) {
    r = g = b = components[0];
} else {
    r = components[0];
    g = components[1];
    b = components[2];            
}
```